# Show that for this rotation matrix $\langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$ using rotation matrix and any vectors

Tags: matrices

> Show that for the rotation matrix
>   $$ A =  
> \begin{pmatrix} 
> \cos(a) & -\sin(a) \\ 
> \sin(a) & \cos(a) 
> \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> $(Ax,Ay)=(x,y)$
>
> With $x$ and $y$ being any vectors contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I am confused on this question thank you for your time.

EDIT: (x,y) is meant to represent the scalar product sorry if this has caused confusion my english is not very good.

Answer (score 3):

First, notice that $\mathbf{A}$ is orthogonal. ($\mathbf{A}^\intercal = \mathbf{A}^{-1}$) Therefore,
$$ (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}) \cdot (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v})
=(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u})^\intercal(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v})
=\mathbf{u}^\intercal\mathbf{A}^\intercal\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}
=\mathbf{u}^\intercal\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}
=\mathbf{u}^\intercal\mathbf{v}
=\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\langle Ax, Ay \rangle = x^TA^TAy$$
Now
$$A^TA = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(a) & \sin(a)\\ -\sin(a) & \cos(a)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \cos(a) & -\sin(a)\\ \sin(a) & \cos(a)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos^2(a)+\sin^2(a) & -\sin(a)\cos(a)+\sin(a)\cos(a)\\ -\sin(a)\cos(a)+\cos(a)\sin(a) & \sin^2(a)+\cos^2(a)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Hence, we have $\langle Ax, Ay \rangle = x^TA^TAy = x^T I y = x^y = \langle x, y\rangle$